# Amazon AppStore for Android Api?

Tags: android, app-store, amazon-appstore

Does anyone know if Amazon has an open API for their Android AppStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current offerings for Developers that want to integrate Amazon into Applications can be found [here](https://developer.amazon.com/). I have not seen a API for the Android App, or any other mobile App for that matter. Which would lead me to believe that they dont provide an API for that. I would suggest that you use the [Web Service API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/), that may be able to work for you depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Full disclosure: My team builds the Amazon Appstore SDK. Even though I work for A2Z, any opinions stated are my own, not my employer's.

---

As of the time of this answer, Amazon has a private beta for the In-App Purchase API. If you want access to the API, please fill out the form at:

http://developer.amazon.com/

You have to create an account to access the request form.